# How to insert row in UITableview in iOS in swift by clicking Button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can i insert new row in `UITableview` by click event of button in IOS in swift? 
I tried my best to do this but my all code not works so please help to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

In your button event just add the data to the array that you use to populate your `tableView` and then make a `tableView.reloadData()`.

So your initial array

```
var data = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
```

Your button event:

```
@IBAction func addData(sender: AnyObject) {
    data.append("Four")
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```